# iOS - UI moves after touching

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3

I have a view with an image and two labels. It looks like this:

[image: View in storyboard]

It has a constraint with 0 to the top. But it looks like this in real:

[image]

The whole view is like 50px below the titlebar. But when I click somewhere on the view, it slides up and looks like this:

[image]

It should be like this, but why is first like 50px below the position I want? When you look close you can see that the image moves a little bit into the title.

Comment: Is it not exactly `64px` what is missing? I think there is a wrong setup for your navigation controller.

Comment: Keep 64pixel below instead of 50px. And for more precise answer post your constraints here.

Comment: Put your image after 64px of top .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a little hard to guess, but try this 2 step:

1)
YouStoryboard.storyboard > YouViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets

[image]

2) Click on your image in storyboard > Attributes inspector> check "Clip to Bounds"